# Constrained least squares where at least one of two coefficients is zero

Tags: regression, least-squares, linear, constrained-regression

I have a linear model with a bunch of variables a number of linear constraints on these variables. I am currently using quadratic programming to solve this constrained least squares problem.

However, I now want to impose an additional constraint: Either the coefficient of the first regressor or the coefficient of the second regressor must be 0 (and possibly both can be 0). That is to say, it should not be the case that the coefficients of the first and second regressors are both positive.

Ultimately, I will want to impose a number of constraints of this nature, where certain pairs of coefficients must satisfy the property that it cannot be the case that both coefficients in the pair are nonzero.

Can this be done in a clean way, using quadratic programming or otherwise?

Comment: this is a nonconvex constraint, so not achievable with (positive semidefinite continuous) quadratic programming. You could use a quadratic program with integer constraints. So it's a tough nut, but see the Exclusive Lasso, e.g. http://proceedings.mlr.press/v9/zhou10a/zhou10a.pdf

Comment: @John I might be misunderstanding, but this looks exceptionally easy: isn't it just a pair of problems where in each problem one of the coefficients is set to zero?

Comment: @whuber Enumeration will work, but there will be combinatorially many to enumerate as the number of pairs increases (the part of OP's question beginning with "Ultimately").

Comment: @JohnMadden Thanks for your comments. Yeah enumeration is possible but very computationally inefficient given the number of pairs and the size of the dataset I'm dealing with so was hoping to avoid that, which may not be possible given what you mentioned

Comment: Interesting question, but not very much related to statistics or ML. You might want to click that "Flag" link and request that a moderator migrate it to [OR.SE](https://or.stackexchange.com/), you might get better answers there.

Comment: @galpo it is possible to avoid that if you are OK with only locally optimal solutions. In such a case I would recommend proximal gradient methods with an exclusive lasso proximal operator, but I really am a hammer and everything looks like that nail to me.